# Do Orientdb use the deleted vertex or edge memory?

Tags: graph, orientdb

Suppose we have an edge or a vertex but we don't need that vertex anymore when we delete that vertex does orientdb use that space again that was allocated to the deleted vertex or edge.

Answer (score 1):

The space is reused, but the RID (Record ID) is never recycled.