# OrientDB: RIDs assigned once and forever?

Tags: orientdb

Imagine the following:

- a newly created node gets for example the RID #19:2
- some time later that node #19:2 gets deleted (so the id would be theoretically available again)

Now my question is: Is there a possibility/risk, that the RID #19:2 could be assigned again to another newly created node or can I be sure, that it won't be assigned ever again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luca Garulli (Founder and CEO of OrientDB LTD) wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160635/do-orientdb-use-the-deleted-vertex-or-edge-memory) on SO:

> the RID (Record ID) is never recycled.

But it would probably be wise in general to regard it as an internal "implementation detail" whenever possible, if only because @rid values might not survive export/import.  (For this reason, I think it would be nice to have a shorthand for `SELECT FROM <class> WHERE <id> = <value>`)